# Display image in OpenCV using OpenGL in C/C++

Tags: c++, c, opencv, opengl

I tried displaying an image (which is stored in a `cv::Mat`) in an OpenGL window (created with `cv::namedWindow`) using `cv::imshow`, like so:

```
cv::Mat cvImage = ...;
cv::namedWindow("test", cv::WINDOW_OPENGL);
cv::imshow("test", cvImage);
```

The problem is, the program crashes with the following error:

```
OpenCV(4.4.0-dev) Error: OpenGL API call (Can't load OpenGL extension [glBindBuffer]) in IntGetProcAddress
```

Why is that? Is `cv::imshow` supposed to take a `cv::ogl::Texture2D` instead of `cv::Mat` when using OpenGL? I tried the following and it leads to the same error:

```
cv::ogl::Texture2D texture = cv::ogl::Texture2D(
            height,
            width,
            cv::ogl::Texture2D::Format::RGB,
            true
            );
texture.copyFrom(cvImage, true);
cv::imshow("test", texture);
```

What could be the problem? I don't want to import OpenGL headers as well, I thought the flag `cv::WINDOW_OPENGL` was enough to get me going. Thanks.

Comment: looks like `glBindBuffer` is not getting loaded properly, I'm not sure how openCV does it but I usually use a library like GLEW to properly link these functions for me.

Comment: In your cmake list `WITH_OPENGL` on or off =